# SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified in Laravel

Tags: laravel, ms-access

After I install the `composer require moodlesbv/laravel-msaccess` and follow the instructions on how to setup the connection.
I already downloaded the `accessdatabaseengine_X64`, and also already set up the DataSource in ODBC Data Source (x64) but I got this error.

Laravel 6, PHP 7.4

```
exception: "Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception"
file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\hris_mirdc\hris\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception.php"
line: 18
message: "SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"
```

**database.php** config file

```
'connections' => [
    'access' => [
        'driver' => 'pdo_access',
        'connection_string' => 'dsn={UNIS}',
        'username' => 'unisuser',
        'password' => 'unisamho',
        'table_prefix' => '',
    ]
],
```

[This is the phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruBV0.jpg)

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290532) help you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data source name not found, and no default driver specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290532/data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified)

Comment: @Dan nope, i already tried it but the same error appeared. I added the phpinfo in my question.